# Resize IFRAME to Remove Scrollbars

Tags: javascript, dom, angularjs

I have an iframe on my page that I want resized every time the contents changes so that there are no scrollbars. The contents of the frame changes frequently without changing the URL. I want all of the content from the frame to show all the time, without having the screen flicker while the frame is resizing. The parent and frame are on the same domain.

Right now I call a function to set the frame size whenever I think the size has changed. How do I do this without calling this function everywhere?

If it helps, I am using angularJS.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more compatible to just specify `overflow: hidden" in the embedded document?

Comment: Good point. I don't want overflow to be hidden.

Comment: try to use the scrolling:no    you can follow the properties here  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can get the iFrames content height by [iframe]`.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight`. If you don’t know when the the content size changes you have to check it manually by using `setInterval()`.

Comment: setInterval is a good idea. However, this causes the screen to flicker. Is there something that would not cause the screen to flicker?

Answer (score 1):

Try [iframe-resizer](http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/), a drop-in js module for resizing iframes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, call the re-size function in a event listener, when ever the iframe loads this will be triggered

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    var resizeFunction= function() {$("#myIframe").css({
       height: iframe.$("body").outerHeight()
    });};
    if(iframe.addEventListener){
        iframe.addEventListener('load', resizeFunction, true);
    }else if(iframe.attachEvent){
        iframe.attachEvent('onload',resizeFunction);
    }
```

Comment: This only resizes on load. The contents of my frame changes all the time, with no loads.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function wich I used on one of my site. I modified the code to be put in a directive.

Note : In the iframe your container must have the ID `ifrm_container`

```
<iframe resize-iframe id="iframe" src="...">

.directive('resize-iframe', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function ( scope, elm, attrs ) {

        var container = elm.contentWindow.document.getElementById('ifrm_container'); // Iframe container. Usualy a div. 

        function autoResize(){
             ifrmNewHeight = container.offsetHeight; // New height of the document.

             if(ifrmNewHeight !== ifrmOldHeight) {
                ifrmOldHeight = ifrmNewHeight + 30; // +30 for no scrollbar.
                ifrm.style.height= (ifrmNewHeight + 30) + "px"; // Set iframe style.
             }

            setTimeout(autoResize, 250);
        }
      // First call of autoResize().
      autoResize();
  };
});
```

I have tested this solution on all browser even IE7 and it works well but not in a directive (changed some element).

**THIS DIRECTIVE IS NOT TESTED**

Comment: Wrapping Max's answer into a directive is a pretty good idea. However, it still has the same drawback of screen flicker.