# Execute Function After Every Digest Loop Before DOM Render

Tags: angularjs

I would like to execute a piece of code after every $digest loop, after the DOM has been constructed, but before the render. I want this on *every* $apply, not just the ones after linking/compiling. Where do I add my code?

I am not going to provide my particular use case because I would like to know how to do this in general. If you would like to help me with my particular problem, I have a separate question: [Resize IFRAME to Remove Scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887828/resize-iframe-to-remove-scrollbars)

Comment: you can do $rootScope.$watch(function(){ ... }). The logic in the fn will be called every $digest loop

Comment: @IanHaggerty It works! Thanks! Would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: @IanHaggerty This runs once for each cycle of the loop, right?

Comment: Don't thank me, thank thinkster :)
http://www.thinkster.io/pick/51dc70a1fc30e44f96000001/digest

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can do `$rootScope.$watch(function(){ ... })`. The logic in the fn will be called every `$digest` loop

Comment: I found it's important to make sure you don't return something weird or you can get infinite digests happening. `return true;` will fix that.